# Controlling data edit of form objects while navigating the saved records

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have built a form on table which will navigate showing data stored in each record in the table.

I need to restrict the edition of  data  while navigating records from the form. Edition can be permitted by clicking a command button for example (Edit) to change the stroed data.

Can this happen?

If so, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Allow Edits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb237260%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property of the form to control whether the user can change data or not. Note that Allow Edits set to false, even unbound controls cannot be changed. Ensure that you switch Allow Edits to false in the Current Event for the form after you have set it to true in your button click.

```
 Me.AllowEdits = True ''False
```